# Managing different Return Types when calling a Stored Procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework to call some Stored Procedures to return results for various reports.  I would like some of these SPs to return some additional columns under certain conditions based on the input parameters.  The calling application will know what to expect based on these input parameters.

As I am using EF, I have to specify a specific Return Type (e.g. `mysproc_Result`) however I would like to present a different return type under certain conditions.

Is there a way to do this or am I going to have to resort to calling the SP at a lower level , passing in the correct Return Type?

NOTE: This question isn't about returning Multiple Result Sets.
Thanks.

Comment: This question may get transferred to StackOverflow.com

Comment: Sorry.  I chose carefully which Stack Exchange to place this in and I thought _Programmers_ would be the most appropriate.

Comment: Why not include the extra columns as part of your regular result set and set them to null or zero if they are not filled by procedure?